# Pdb go to a frame in exception within exception

Tags: python, exception, pdb

I am debugging a program named `a.py` using pdb

```
def f(x) :
    x / x

def g(x) :
    try :
        f(x)
    except Exception as e :
        assert 0

g(0)
```

When I run the program using `python3 -m pdb a.py`, the program stops at `assert 0` line, and I get the following error information:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 6, in g
    f(x)
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 2, in f
    x / x
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1667, in main
    pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/pdb.py", line 1548, in _runscript
    self.run(statement)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/bdb.py", line 434, in run
    exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 11, in <module>
    g(0)
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 9, in g
    assert 0
AssertionError
```

and the stack is (shown using `bt` command):

```
(Pdb) bt
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/pdb.py(1667)main()
-> pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/pdb.py(1548)_runscript()
-> self.run(statement)
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/bdb.py(434)run()
-> exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  <string>(1)<module>()->None
  /tmp/a.py(11)<module>()->None
-> g(0)
> /tmp/a.py(9)g()
-> assert 0
(Pdb)
```

The problem is, I cannot go to function f to debug `x / x` simply using `up` and `down`, because my stack ends at the g function.

How should I debug such exceptions within exceptions? What about exceptions within exceptions within exceptions ...?

Comment: So, your `assert 0` is at the same call depth as `f(0)` which is why you can't jump back into it and debug it. Your `except` is catching the error raised by `f(0)` and then `pdb` is breaking on the `AssertionError` because it's uncaught. What's your end goal exactly? If you're trying to debug any uncaught exceptions with `pdb`, you've already caught the one being raised by `f(0)` so you're not going to be able to. You can place a `pdb.set_trace()` in your except block and inspect the raised exception though, or you can re-raise the exception in the `except` block.

Comment: In my real program, `x / x` is the annoying part that I want to debug (e.g. I want to see the value of x using pdb), but I need try & except in `g(x)` to print an user friendly message which shows that an error occurred (but not fixing the error). Thus, I have to use `pdb` to debug an **caught** error. Can you explain more on the `pdb.set_trace()` part? Providing an example will be appreciated.

Comment: pdb.set_trace() allow you to set a breakpoint where you want in the code, if you put it before the x / x and run it, program will stop and you will be able to inspect all variable at this point. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.set_trace

Comment: Putting pdb.set_trace() directly before `x / x` does not solve my problem. Suppose that function g calls `f(1000), f(999), f(998), ..., f(0)`, then I would have to debug one thousand times before finding the real error (if I do not know which value of x causes the error)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**tl;dr:** You can debug the inner exception even after you've already entered post-mortem debugging for the outer exception. Here's how to do it:

1. Enter interactive mode from `pdb` (type `interact` into the `pdb` prompt).
2. Run:

   ```py
   import pdb, sys; pdb.post_mortem(sys.last_value.__context__.__traceback__)
   ```

   *Note:*

   - Replace `__context__` with `__cause__` if your exception is explicitly chained; also append more `__context__`s or `__cause__`s if it's nested deeper.
   - If you're inspecting a handled exception (one that was caught in a try-catch), replace `sys.last_value` with `sys.exc_info()[1]`. If you're unsure, inspect the exception values before proceeding. (Thanks [@The Doctor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2808241/the-doctor) for pointing this out in comments)
3. This starts a new `pdb` session that allows you to debug the inner exception.

The following is a long and detailed explanation of why this work. Before diving into the solution, I'll first explain some related concepts:

---

**Chained Exceptions**

The "exception within exception" here is known as [**chained exceptions**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/). Exceptions can be chained explicitly or implicitly:

```py
>>>: try:
...:     raise ZeroDivisionError
...: except Exception as inner_exc:
...:     raise ValueError  # implicit chaining
...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1ae22e81c853> in <module>
      1 try:
----> 2     raise ZeroDivisionError
      3 except Exception as inner_exc:

ZeroDivisionError:

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-1ae22e81c853> in <module>
      2     raise ZeroDivisionError
      3 except Exception as inner_exc:
----> 4     raise ValueError  # implicit chaining

ValueError:


>>>: try:
...:     raise ZeroDivisionError
...: except Exception as inner_exc:
...:     raise ValueError from inner_exc  # explicit chaining
...:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ZeroDivisionError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-63c49fcb10a2> in <module>
      1 try:
----> 2     raise ZeroDivisionError
      3 except Exception as inner_exc:

ZeroDivisionError:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-63c49fcb10a2> in <module>
      2     raise ZeroDivisionError
      3 except Exception as inner_exc:
----> 4     raise ValueError from inner_exc  # explicit chaining

ValueError:
```

If we catch the outer exception as `outer_exc`, then we can inspect the inner exception through `outer_exc.__cause__` (if explicitly chained) or `outer_exc.__context__` (if implicitly chained).

---

**Post-mortem Debugging**

Running a script with `python -m pdb` allows the Python debugger to enter [**post-mortem debugging**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdb.post_mortem) mode on exception. "Post-mortem" here means "after the exception has occurred". You can do the same from an IPython console or within Jupyter notebooks by running the `%debug` magic.

You can also manually enter post-mortem debugging mode if you have access to the traceback object. Luckily, traceback objects are stored on the exception object itself as the `__traceback__` attribute:

```py
>>> try:
...     raise ZeroDivisionError:
... except Exception as e:
...     # Variable `e` is local to this block, so we store it in another variable
...     # to extend its lifetime.
...     exc = e

>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.post_mortem(exc.__traceback__)
> <ipython-input-8-e5b5ed89e466>(2)<module>()
-> raise ZeroDivisionError
(Pdb)
```

---

**Debugging Chained Exceptions**

Now we can try debugging the chained exceptions! Assume we're already in post-mortem debugging mode for the outer exception. What we need to do is:

1. Get the outer exception object;
2. Access the inner exception object, and get its traceback;
3. Call `pdb.post_mortem()` on that traceback object.
   Here's what we do:

```bash
# First, enter interactive mode to execute commands.
(Pdb) interact
*interactive*
# The current exception is stored in `sys.exc_info()`.  This gives back a tuple
# of (exception type, exception value, traceback).
>>> import sys
>>> sys.exc_info()
(<class 'AssertionError'>, AssertionError(), <traceback object at 0x10c683e00>)
>>> sys.exc_info()[1]
AssertionError()
# In our case, the inner exception is implicitly chained.  Access it through
# the `__context__` attribute.
>>> sys.exc_info()[1].__context__
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
# Get its traceback, and enter post-mortem debugging.
>>> sys.exc_info()[1].__context__.__traceback__
<traceback object at 0x10c683c80>
>>> import pdb
>>> pdb.post_mortem(sys.exc_info()[1].__context__.__traceback__)
> test.py(2)f()
-> x / x
(Pdb)
```

There you have it! You can now debug the inner exception using normal `pdb` commands, such as walking through the stack or inspecting local variables.

Comment: `sys.exc_info()[1].__context__.__traceback__` didn't work for me but `sys.last_value.__context__.__traceback__` did.

Comment: @TheDoctor `sys.last_value` holds the last unhandled exception, while `sys.exc_info()[1]` is the last handled exception. I think you're right that `sys.last_value` is probably more suitable here; the exception we want to inspect is probably unhandled. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: sys.last_value does not exist in the example that I'm working with which uses explicit chaining (https://gist.github.com/kerrick-js/385993d88a804748cd4f094f0032f542). I think sys.exc_info()[1] is better.

Also, you need to prefix the import with !, otherwise the last exception becomes AttributeError("'Pdb' object has no attribute 'do_import'").

So for me the full command that worked is
`!import sys, pdb; pdb.post_mortem(sys.exc_info()[1].__context__.__traceback__)`

Comment: @KerrickStaley I tried running your example and the exception showed up in `sys.last_value`; `sys.exc_info()` gave me `(None, None, None)`. Also, prefixing with `!` is only necessary in the `pdb` prompt, once you enter interactive mode, it just works like an ordinary Python REPL.

Comment: This solution didn't work for me because I'm using `pytest --pdb` to catch the exception and by the time the post-mortem prompt is entered, `sys.exc_info == (None, None, None)`.

Comment: I filed https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/11512 to request improved support in pytest.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs Have you tried looking at `sys.last_value`? I tried running the example in your GitHub issue with `pytest --pdb`, and was able to perform post-mortem debugging from the exception stored in `sys.last_value`. For reference, I'm using pytest 7.4.0 and Python 3.10.12.

Comment: @ZecongHu You're right. At least in the minimal example, `sys.last_value` is available. I think my specific situation was more complicated and I oversimplified it when attempting to distill a reproducer. I suspect that "fixtures" were in play that affected the exception state. I should have linked to the project I was attempting to debug, because at this point, I don't recall how I encountered the issue, but IIRC, neither `sys.last_value` nor `sys.exc_info()` had the necessary context. I'll continue to investigate in the pytest bug.

Answer (score 2):

Actually re-raising the exception (option 3 in 
[wholevinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/769971/wholevinski)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095739/7709727)) solves my problem, since it does not require me to modify function f. 
Here is the code:

```
'''Option 3'''
def f(x) :
    x -= 1
    x / x

def g(x) :
    try :
        for i in range(x, 0, -1) :
            print(f(i))
    except Exception as e :
        raise e

g(10)
```

Pdb output of the stack:

```
(Pdb) bt
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/pdb.py(1667)main()
-> pdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/pdb.py(1548)_runscript()
-> self.run(statement)
  /usr/lib64/python3.6/bdb.py(434)run()
-> exec(cmd, globals, locals)
  <string>(1)<module>()->None
  /tmp/a.py(13)<module>()->None
-> g(10)
  /tmp/a.py(11)g()
-> raise e
  /tmp/a.py(9)g()
-> print(f(i))
> /tmp/a.py(4)f()
-> x / x
(Pdb)
```

Comment: Welp, good on you for proving out option 3 and going with it! Glad it worked out.